# variable lengths differ in R

Tags: r

I am getting the error above when trying to use the cv.lm fucntion. Please see my code

```
sample<-read.csv("UU2_1_lung_cancer.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",",na.string="NA")
  sample1<-sample[2:2000,3:131]
  samplex<-sample[2:50,3:131]
  y<-as.numeric(sample1[1,]) 
  y<-as.numeric(sample1[2:50,2]) 
  x1<-as.numeric(sample1[2:50,3])
  x2<-as.numeric(sample1[2:50,4])
  x11<-x1[!is.na(y)]
  x12<-x2[!is.na(y)]
  y<-y[!is.na(y)]
  fit1 <- lm(y ~ x11 + x12, data=sample)
  fit1
  x3<-as.numeric(sample1[2:50,5])
  x4<-as.numeric(sample1[2:50,6])
  x13<-x3[!is.na(y)]
  x14<-x4[!is.na(y)]
  fit2 <- lm(y ~ x11 + x12 + x13 + x14, data=sample)
  anova(fit1,fit2)
  install.packages("DAAG")
  library("DAAG")
  cv.lm(df=samplex, fit1, m=10) # 3 fold cross-validation
```

Any insight will be appreciated.

```
Example of data
ID       peak height     LCA001 LCA002  LCA003
N001786 32391.111   0.397   0.229   -0.281
N005356 32341.473   0.397   -0.655  -1.301
N002416 32215.474   -0.703  -0.214  -0.901
GS239   31949.777   0.354   0.118   0.272
N016343 31698.853   0.226   0.04    -0.006
N003255 31604.978   0.024    NA -0.534
N004358 31356.597   -0.252  -0.022  -0.407
N000122 31168.09    -0.487  -0.533  -0.134
GS10564 31106.103   -0.156  -0.141  -1.17
GS17987 31043.876    NA     0.253   0.553
N003674 30876.207   0.109   0.093   0.07
```

Please see the example of the data above

Comment: post a sample of your data needed to run this code, and at what point do you get the error

Comment: ID peak height LCA001 LCA002 LCA003
N001786 32391.111 0.397 0.229 -0.281
N005356 32341.473 0.397 -0.655 -1.301
N002416 32215.474 -0.703 -0.214 -0.901
GS239 31949.777 0.354 0.118 0.272
N016343 31698.853 0.226 0.04 -0.006
N003255 31604.978 0.024 -0.17 -0.534
N004358 31356.597 -0.252 -0.022 -0.407
N000122 31168.09 -0.487 -0.533 -0.134
GS10564 31106.103 -0.156 -0.141 -1.17
GS17987 31043.876        0.253 0.553
N003674 30876.207 0.109 0.093 0.07

Comment: @rawr: Here is the data sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are using `lm(..)` incorrectly, or at least in a very unconventional way. The purpose of specifying the `data=sample` argument is so that the formula uses references to columns of the `sample`. Generally, *it is a very bad practice* to use free-standing data in the formula reference.

So try this:

```
## not tested...
sample <- read.csv(...)
colnames(sample)[2:6] <- c("y","x1","x2","x3","x4")
fit1 <- lm(y~x1+x2, data=sample[2:50,],na.action=na.omit)
library(DAAG)
cv.lm(df=na.omit(sample[2:50,]),fit1,m=10)
```

This will give columns 2:6 the appropriate names and then use those in the formula. The argument `na.action=na.omit` tells the `lm(...)` function to exclude all rows where there is an NA value in *any* of the relevant columns. This is actually the default, so it is not needed in this case, but included for clarity.

Finally, `cv.lm(...)` uses it's second argument to find the formula definition, so in your code:

```
cv.lm(df=samplex, fit1, m=10)
```

is equivalent to:

```
cv.lm(df=samplex,y~x11+x12,m=10)
```

Since there are (presumeably) no columns named `x11` and `x12` in `samplex`, and since you define these vectors externally, `cv.lm(...)` throws the error you are getting.

Comment: In this equation, how do one handle the NA?

Comment: Good point. Evidently, you have to omit NAs explicitly from the `df` argument. See my edits. This seems to work on the sample you provided. BTW: it is *much* better to post the data as an edit to the question, rather than in a comment. Type `dput(mydata)` and paste the output into your question.

Comment: @jlhowards: I cannot see your edits. Can you please resend what you tested

Comment: Thank you my pc was acting up. I got it Thanks