# Leaps package in R returns "variable lengths differ" error

Tags: r, regression

I'm using the `leaps` package in R to run `regsubsets`:

```
a <- regsubsets(in_var~paste(predictors,collapse="+"),data=x,nbest=10,matrix=T)
```

And get an error message:

```
Error in model.frame.default(data = x, matrix = T, formula = rating ~  : variable lengths differ (found for '(matrix)')
```

(Note, it makes no difference if I copy out the predictors list manually or not).

I've just tried with the attitude dataset, e.g.:

```
data(attitude)
attitude <- na.omit(attitude)
regsubsets(rating~.,data=attitude,nbest=10,matrix=T)
```

And get the same error.  My dataset is similar, but has more variables and the in_var is a 1-3 score (elsewhere I collapse it to a binary, for which I could later run a logistic).  Not sure if I'm asking a `statistics question` or an `R` question here...

A few questions (e.g. [Error in model.frame.default ...... variable lengths differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771284/error-in-model-frame-default-variable-lengths-differ) ; [variable lengths differ in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183560/variable-lengths-differ-in-r)  ... ) deal with this, but I've already done na.omit on the dataframe, so I shouldn't have any missing values resulting in uneven vectors.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
a <- regsubsets(y=as.matrix(x[c("in_var")]),x=as.matrix(x[c(predictors)]),nbest=10)
```

Presumably the issue is that `regsubsets` requires a `matrix` (not df)